# Why scipy.interpolate.griddata and scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline return different values?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to draw the surface at a given points. And I want to get the z coordinate for an arbitrary point. I can't understand why scipy.interpolate.griddata and scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline return different values for the same x and y coordinates. Where did I go wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata, RectBivariateSpline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x_list = np.array([  10.0,  10.0,    0.0,   0.0])
y_list = np.array([   0.0,  10.0,   10.0,   0.0])
z_list = np.array([103.95, 105.5, 104.85, 104.6])

xi = np.linspace(min(x_list), max(x_list),11)
yi = np.linspace(min(y_list), max(y_list),11)

grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

grid_z1 = griddata((x_list, y_list), z_list, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
grid_z2 = griddata((x_list, y_list), z_list, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
grid_z3 = griddata((x_list, y_list), z_list, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

z = RectBivariateSpline(xi, yi,  grid_z2, kx=1, ky=1, s=0)

print z(10.0, 0.0)[0,0] #return 104.85!!! Must be 103.95.

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
surf = ax1.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z1)
ax1.set_xlabel(u'X')
ax1.set_ylabel(u'Y')
ax1.set_zlabel(u'Z')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
surf = ax2.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z2)
ax2.set_xlabel(u'X')
ax2.set_ylabel(u'Y')
ax2.set_zlabel(u'Z')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223, projection='3d')
surf = ax3.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z3)
ax3.set_xlabel(u'X')
ax3.set_ylabel(u'Y')
ax3.set_zlabel(u'Z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Aren't they just different interpolation methods?  You can't expect the values to be exactly identical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your code, but you might be falling prey to the Matlabesque behavior of `np.meshgrid`. See this discussion [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3164). TLDR: change the order of inputs of meshgrid and try again

Comment: Yeah, just change: `grid_y, grid_x = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)` and I think stuff should work now. (If you confirm this is the issue, please explain what happened in an answer so that people who come back to this question know exactly what's going on)

Comment: I use `grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi, indexing = 'ij')` and everything works correctly. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I use parameter `indexing = 'ij'` and my code works correctly.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata, RectBivariateSpline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_list = np.array([  10.0,  10.0,   0.0,    0.0])
y_list = np.array([  0.0,  10.0,   10.0,    0.0])
z_list = np.array([103.95, 105.5, 104.85, 104.6])

xi = np.linspace(min(x_list), max(x_list),11)
yi = np.linspace(min(y_list), max(y_list),11)

grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi, indexing = 'ij')

grid_z1 = griddata((x_list, y_list), z_list, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
grid_z2 = griddata((x_list, y_list), z_list, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
grid_z3 = griddata((x_list, y_list), z_list, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

z = RectBivariateSpline(xi, yi, grid_z2, kx=1, ky=1, s=0)

print z(10.0, 0.0)[0,0] #return 103.95)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
surf = ax1.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z1)
ax1.set_xlabel(u'X')
ax1.set_ylabel(u'Y')
ax1.set_zlabel(u'Z')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
surf = ax2.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z2)
ax2.set_xlabel(u'X')
ax2.set_ylabel(u'Y')
ax2.set_zlabel(u'Z')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223, projection='3d')
surf = ax3.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z3)
ax3.set_xlabel(u'X')
ax3.set_ylabel(u'Y')
ax3.set_zlabel(u'Z')

plt.show()
```